# Unable to catch "UnreachableBrowserException" in try/catch block

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to catch an error where the browser is closed when a test is running against a web app. Basically, while the web app is running, I will intentionally close the browser where the web app is running, hoping that it will trigger a simple message stating that the browser is closed rather than a full-blown default error message.

The following code illustrate issue. Within the try block, a test against the web app is executed. During the execution of this block, the browser is closed by clicking on [X].

```
try {
    //testing web app codes 
    try_block = 2;
}
catch(UnreachableBrowserException e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot open browser");
    driver.quit();
}
```

After I closed the browser, I was expecting that the catch block is executed. Instead of that, it is now showing the full blown `UnreachableBrowserException` error message.

[image]

Comment: What does the _full blown developmental error message_ says?

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added the screenshot of the full blown error message

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is caught, you can see in the screenshot you added the message `"Cannot open browser"`.

The exception you see is actually from the `catch` block on `driver.quit();` when you are trying to close already closed browser.

Comment: @supputuri Oh, I am using a very old version. v2.53

Comment: @Guy, May I also seek your help in another try/catch question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467290/try-catch-function-not-exiting-catch-block ?